# External CSS Files Rendering Differently

Tags: css

On my website (http://www.mtscollective.com), I've removed the CSS from Blogger's HTML template, and hosted the stylesheets externally.

However, now the 'Oswald' font isn't rendering and some of my responsive design (the header is cut off) style differently.

What could be the reason for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume the CSS font references to a relative path. On the page the paths are relative to the URL and in the external page it's relative to the external CSS file. But you didn't post any code so I'm only assuming.